# Manipulating and simplification of Boolean functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How is the function ((p v (r v q)) ^ ~(~q ^ ~r) is equal to the function (q v r).
Can anyone show  how is this simplified using formulas asuch as De Morgans ans etc???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align} & \quad (p\lor (r \lor q)) \land \lnot (\lnot q \land \lnot r)\\ \\ &\equiv (p \lor r\lor q)\land (\lnot \lnot q \lor \lnot \lnot r)\\ \\ 
& \equiv (p \lor q \lor r)\land (q \lor r)\\ \\
& \equiv [p \land (q \lor r)] \lor [(q\lor r)\land (q \lor r)]\\ \\
& \equiv [p \land (q \lor r)] \lor (q\lor r)\\ \\
& \equiv (p \lor T)\land (q \lor r)\\ \\
& \equiv q \lor r
\end{align}$$

Comment: can this answer be further explained by which rules are being used and how T in (p∨T)∧(q∨r) comes in.

Comment: That's the distributive property: $(p \lor T) \land (q \lor r) = [p\land (q \lor r)] \lor [T \land (q\lor r) = [p \land (q \lor r)]\lor (q\lor r)$. I went in the reverse direction.

Comment: 1. DeMorgan's, 2. Double negation, 3.Distributive property, 4. "Simplification": $a \lor a = a$. 5.Distributive property. 6....